# “Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store” - even when add new key

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, code-signing, strongname

I cannot build projects with a strong name key signing - the message in the title always comes up.

Yes the project was initially copied over from another machine. However even if I add a new key via the Signing tab in Project Properties, this error is still shown.

I have tried running Visual Studio as an Administrator and have tried manually adding the keys to Windows Certificate Store.

Help!

Edit: I don't get this error with a new project, but I'd quite like to get this existing project working. It won't work even if I create a new certificate!

Comment: What type of VS project? Have you unchecked the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" on the Project Properties Signing Tab as well?

Comment: @Simon Mourier, if I uncheck that option then the file won't be signed. I want it to be signed! It's a C# project. Works fine on my main development machine, just not on the laptop.

Comment: Is the error message displayed in your build log, or in some other way? It may help if you copy and paste the log.

Comment: An error in the build log: “Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store”

Comment: I didn't see the lines of code in the accepted answer. But this worked for me:  I created a new key in VS2015. I unclicked Sign the Assembly and saved. Then I clicked the Select from File button,chose the file I'd just created, clicked again on Sign the assembly, and saved. Rebuilt.

Answer (score 380, accepted):

I've finally found the solution.

1. Edit the `.csproj` file for the project in question.
2. Delete the following lines of code:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
      <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>...........</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <ManifestKeyFile>xxxxxxxx.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <PropertyGroup>
      <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

Comment: Worked for me too. Any caveats of such action?

Comment: Yup, deleted anything with "Manifest" and it worked :-)

Comment: I wouldn't do this without knowing the repercussions... *does it anyway*

Comment: In my case, Deleting `ManifestCertificateThumbprint` and `ManifestKeyFile` solve the problem.

Comment: @Parrotmaster were there any long term repercussions in the long term for your project?

Comment: @SteveJoppich Haven't noticed any yet. I have since moved to a different company so I'll never know.

Comment: (vs2019 v16.11.24) in works. thanks for info

Comment: Excellent, worked very well for me in VS2022

Comment: If I could give more than one upvote I had did it with no doubt. Thanks

Answer (score 224):

Go to your project's "Properties" within visual studio. Then go to signing tab.

Then make sure Sign the Click Once manifests is turned off.

---

***Updated Instructions:***

**Within your Solution Explorer:**

1. **right click on your project**
2. **click on properties**
3. usually on the left-hand side, **select the "Signing" tab**
4. **check off the Sign the ClickOnce manifests**
5. **Make sure you save!**

[image]

Comment: What you said is fine and should work but didn't. In the end I had to delete the lines of code as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: What does this do/what does this action mean?

Comment: @TrailMix It will modify you config file appropriately.

Comment: this gave me a solution for vs2010 :) up !

Comment: Nice answer! I am using VS2012 and it really works! +1

Comment: @HamidShahid It did not work for you because you need to make the change and then save. Cheers.

Comment: Worked great in VS2010

Comment: This worked on a project that I had originally developed in VS 2017 and we moved to VS 2019.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

It's simple!!

I resolved this problem by following this steps:

1. Open project properties
   [image: img]
2. Click on Signing Tab
3. And uncheck "Sign the assembly"

That's it!!

Comment: This may prevent publishing (if we care) but now it runs.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

Right click on your project → Go to **properties** → Click **signing** which is left side of the screen → **Uncheck** the **Sign the click once manifests** → Save & Build

Comment: In additional,

SignManifest value can be set to false in the .csproj file of the relevant project

Answer (score 13):

1. Open the .csproj file in Notepad.
2. Delete the following information related to signing certificate in the certificate store

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>xxxxx xxxxxx</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
     <ManifestKeyFile>xxxxxxxx.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
   <GenerateManifests>true</GenerateManifests>
   <SignManifests>false</SignManifests>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Go to your projects "Properties" within visual studio. Then go to signing tab.

Then make sure Sign the Click Once manifests is turned off.

OR

1.Open the .csproj file in Notepad.

2.Delete the following information related to signing certificate in the certificate store
    
      xxxxx xxxxxx
      xxxxxxxx.pfx
    true
    false
    `

Worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming this is a personal certificate created by windows on the system you copied your project from, you can use the certificate manager on the system where the project is now and import the certificate.  Start the certificate manager (certmgr) and select the personal certificates then right click below the list  of existing certificates and select import from the tasks.  Use the browse to find the .pfx in the project (the .pfx from the previous system that you copied over with the project).  It should be in the sub-directory with the same name as the project directory.  I am familiar with C# and VS, so if that is not your environment maybe the .pfx will be elsewhere or maybe this suggestion does not apply.  After the import you should get a status message. If you succeeded, the compile certificate error should be gone.[image: certmgr screen]

Comment: Clear and concise!

Answer (score 0):

To sign an assembly with a strong name using attributes

Open `AssemblyInfo.cs` (in `$(SolutionDir)\Properties`)

the `AssemblyKeyFileAttribute` or the `AssemblyKeyNameAttribute`, specifying the name of the file or container that contains the key pair to use when signing the assembly with a strong name.

add the following code:

```
[assembly:AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("keyfile.snk")]
```

Comment: Adding this line doesn't make a difference, I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to manually add keys to the Windows certificate store. The certificate only contains the signed public key. You must also import the *private key* that is associated with the public key in the certificate. A .pfx file contains both public and private keys in a single file. That is what you need to import.

Comment: Thanks but already tried that. Visual Studio should automatically add the certificate when you create a new one anyway. However I have tried adding the .pfx file manually too. Left windows to install it in the correct certificate store and also added it to my personal store.

Comment: The private key is not stored in the certificate store. Please read this, maybe it will help you understand the distinction: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc962112.aspx

Comment: I should add that you can verify that the associated private key is available by opening the certificate property window in certificate manager. If the private key is available, the following text is displayed at the bottom of the General page: "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate". If you do not see that text, the private key is not installed.

Comment: Yes it does say "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate".

Comment: I think that rules out the key or the certificate as the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You said you copied files from another computer. After you copied them, did you 'Unblock' them? Specifically the .snk file should be checked to make sure it is not marked as unsafe.

Comment: It's not blocked, it came over from Windows Live Mesh syncing software. However it's irrelevant since even creating a new key inside Visual Studio on the laptop won't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need just build the project or solution *locally* then removing the signing might be a dead simple solution as others suggest.

But if you have this error on your automation build server like TeamCity where you build your actual release pieces for deployment or distribution you might want to consider how you can get this cert properly installed to the cert store on the build machine, so that you get a signed packages at the end of the build.

Generally it is not recommenced to check-in/commit any **PFX** certificates into source control, so how you get this files on your build server during the build process is a bit another question, but sometimes people do have this file stored along with the solution code, so you can find it in the project folder.

All you need to do is just install this certificate under *proper* account on your build server.

1. Download [PsExec from Windows Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).
2. Open a command prompt, and enter the following. It will spawn a new command prompt, running as **Local System** (assuming that your TeamCity is running under the default Local System account):

   `> psexec.exe -i -s cmd.exe`
3. In this new command prompt, change to the directory containing the certificate and enter the filename to install (change the name of the file to yours):

   `> mykey.pfx`
4. The Import Certificate wizard will start up. Click through and select all the suggested defaults.
5. Run the build.

All credits goes to **[Stuart Noble](http://stuartnoble.com/install-clickonce-certificate-teamcity/)** (and then further to **Laurent Kempé** I believe ☺).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this (again), due to PFX cert not being included in the code, for security.

For local testing, like Debug builds, the lead programmer of this solution had me go into Properties, Signing, click on "Create Test Certificate".  In our setting he said just click ok, but one can put in a strong password here if warranted/needed.