# ClickOnce deployment on Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: deployment, azure-devops, clickonce

I am trying to create ClickOnce deployment on Azure DevOps release pipeline
I create signature, manifest, application, deploy files with certificate
But how can I create the exe and setup file (via Azure DevOps release pipeline)

Comment: The steps to create the setup.exe is simple, you may also check the pics in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58811775/how-to-publish-a-clickonce-application-with-azure-devops-pipeline-on-different-e) to learn which task you need for build and deploy it.

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know if the issue persists or not and I'm willing to help :)

Comment: i have this error when i publish manually with clickonce  "xxx.application.deploy did not succeed."I create .deploy files for all files except manifest and application files.

Comment: Set the System.Debug=true and the run the pipeline again, then we can see the detailed log of this issue. Pelease consider sharing more details about your log in your question, I searched the error above but found nothing :(

Comment: during pipeline there is no error,it is succeed.but after when i run program from .application i see this error xxx.application.deploy did not succeed.But i do not need .application.deploy file .I have application,manifest and several .deploy files

Comment: If you run the command locally with files from your repos, what's the result? Can you share some details about your project structure and pipeline definitions, I can't reproduce same issue on my side :-(

Answer (score 3):

> But how can I create the exe and setup file (via Azure DevOps release
>   pipeline)

Check document [Build ClickOnce applications from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/building-clickonce-applications-from-the-command-line?view=vs-2019): Msbuild has `Publish` target to build and publish the ClickOnce application. It will generate the `setup.exe` you want. See similar hint [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130985/problems-using-msbuild-using-command-line-for-publish-click-once).

And all above is about doing that in local machine, to do similar job in release pipeline you can use [msbuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) or [Visual Studio Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) with `Publish` target(`/t:Publish` as argument).

Then you'll get one `app.publish` folder where the files you want exist there:

[image]

This folder can be used for your further deployment.

**In addition:**

If you meet error like `Unable to find manifest signing certificate in the certificate store`, please check the suggestions in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11957295/10910450).

Comment: Hi Lance Li-MSFT, I just came across this post and your reply to it. It addresses a similar issue I'm having with a WPF app I'm trying to make available as a ClickOnce deployment from an Azure Pipeline. I've followed your instructions in my pipeline. Looking at the log of the last pipeline run, I see that a "bin\Release\app.publish" folder was built. But from there I don't understand how to get that copied over to some website, hosted in Azure, for coworkers to go to in order to run the Setup.exe. Could you help, please?